# SQL Server : how to i write SQL statement in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my sample data in a table:

```
| name  | type |
+-------+------+
|  j    |   1  |
|  j    |   2  |
|  k    |   1  |
|  k    |   1  |
|  k    |   1  |
```

I want to select name who type is all 1.

j has two tuple, but type=1 tuple is only one.

k has three tuple, and type=1 tuple is three.

Therefore result is k

I try to think as possible as i can, but i give up right now :(

Can anyone give me some hints?

Thanks!

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to exclude all NAMEs, where TYPE might be not equal to 1 in any row of the whole table. It can be done via query like this:

```
select *
from your_table as t1
where not exists 
 ( select 1
   from your_table as t2
   where t2.type <> 1
    and t1.name = t2.name)
```

Comment: this is what i need! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you just want the distinct Names, and not all associated records

```
Select name 
 From  YourTable
 Group By Name
 Having min(type)=1 and max(type)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the tuples, by name. Count is an aggregate.  In the group by you put the non-aggregate column - name.  This is ordered in descending order, DESC.  We take the top row only, hence the greatest 'tuple' since we're ordering from greatest to least.

Example Code in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (name char(1), type tinyint)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES ('j', 1), ('j', 2), ('k', 1), ('k', 1), ('k',1)

SELECT TOP 1 
       name
      ,COUNT(name) AS [Tuples]
  FROM @temp
 WHERE type = 1
 GROUP BY name
ORDER BY Tuples DESC
```

Comment: it's not what i wan,t but i also learned something from you. Thanks!!